# Add a single container of docker compose as a service of docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a written a docker compose file and one of the container is only taking high CPU utilisation ,so my plan is  to add only that container as a service  into docker swarm. Isn't  possible to add , i don't want to add whole compose stack as a service.

Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add serive to swarm by image tag name, so answer is yes, you can.